# Could there be latent infections in the human population that we don't know of?

Tags: population-biology, parasitology

Herpes simplex 1 virus and toxoplasmosis are common infections that that many of use have (65% and 10% of americans, respectively). Both of these are chronic, latent infections that can occasionally cause problems (i.e. in HIV patients) but most of the time don't.

Could there by many other such common, latent infections in the human population that we don't know of? Do we have any idea of how many there would be?

Comment: Given the right (or wrong, depending on the perspective) circumstances, even your body's own microbiome can turn against you - a human body cultivates thousands of bacterial colonies that, if something disturbs their balance (e.g. antibiotics), can cause severe metabolic disturbances

Comment: @Sty: The micro-biome normally doesn't infect people, i.e. it's technically "outside" of the body.

Comment: @KevinKostlan From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenteritis) `Gastroenteritis, also known as infectious diarrhea, is inflammation of the gastrointestinal tract [..] Gastroenteritis can be due to infections by viruses, bacteria, parasites, and fungus.`

Comment: @Remi: Key word "normally". Gastroenteritis seems to be a more "typical" infectious disease, which represents pathological conditions (unless most people who are actually "infected" show minimal symptoms and "don't" have the disease, where "infection" means infiltration into tissue).